# JQuery datepicker : limiting dates not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Hi I made a calendar for your help.

However the if statement to compare from and to doesn't work correct.

the rule is

let's assume that From and To are selected.

then if From date is greater than To date, then To date has to be set on the date at 3 month later than the From date. but if not To date doesn't need to be changed.

I don't know why the if statement is not working.

and is there a debug tool? like debug() in PHP?

Please let me know.

Thank you

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        maxDate: 0,
        showButtonPanel : true,
        closeText : 'Reset',
        onClose: function () {
            var today = new Date();
            var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            var from3 = from;
            from3.setMonth(from3.getMonth() + 3);//3 month limit
            var to = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
            var tdate = $("#from").datepicker("getDate");

            if(to == ""){
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", today);
            }
            else{
                if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
                    $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                    $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", today);
                }
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", today);
                tdate.setMonth(tdate.getMonth() + 3);
                tdate = (tdate>today) ? today : tdate;
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", tdate);

                if(from3 > to){
                    $('#to').datepicker('setDate', from3);
                }
                else if(from > to){
                    $('#to').datepicker('setDate', from);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        maxDate: 0,
        showButtonPanel : true,
        closeText : 'Reset',
        onClose: function () {
            var today = new Date();
            var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            var from3 = from;
            from3.setMonth(from3.getMonth() + 3);//3 month limit
            var to = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');

            if(from == ""){
                $('#from').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', today);
            }
            else{
                if ($(window.event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
                    $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                    $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", today);
                }
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", today);
                if(from3 > to){
                    $('#from').datepicker('setDate', from3);
                }
                else if(from > to){
                    $('#to').datepicker('setDate', from3);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: replicate the problem in a fiddle and share with us

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/ddg664rn/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fiddle provided in comments, here is my version:

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        maxDate: 0,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        closeText: 'Reset',
        onClose: function (e) {
            var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            var to = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');

            if(from != null) {
                // Limit the value of "TO" date to current "FROM" date
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", from);

                // Set "TO" date to "FROM" + 3 months if it is currently less than FROM
                if(to != null && to < from) {
                    $('#to').datepicker('setDate', new Date(from.getFullYear(), from.getMonth() + 3, from.getDate()));
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        maxDate: 0,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        closeText: 'Reset',
        onClose: function (e) {
            var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            var to = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');

            if(to != null) {
                // Limit the value of "FROM" date to current "TO" date
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", to);

                // Set "FROM" date to "TO" - 3 months if it is currently more than TO
                if(from != null && from > to) {
                    $('#from').datepicker('setDate', new Date(to.getFullYear(), to.getMonth() - 3, to.getDate()));
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here you can find a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ddg664rn/13/

In this version, the dates are changed at + / - 3 months if the conditions are not met (that is to say if you set a FORM date greater than TO date, or a TO date less than FORM date).
I added minDate / maxDate that also limit wrong input: after you select a FROM date, the TO date cannot be less than this value.

Comment: Thank you. It was not the one i wanted but I edit your code to make correct. Thank you